# How does Mocha generate a mock out of MyRubyClass.new in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mockachino

My background is Java and I am new to Ruby. I saw a mocking/stubbing framework called Mocka. I saw this example test method:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mocha/test_unit'

class MiscExampleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  # ...

  def test_mocking_an_instance_method_on_a_real_object
    product = Product.new
    product.expects(:save).returns(true)
    assert product.save
  end

  #...
end
```

What mechanism was used to "automatically" create a mock object of Person class (or object)? Not sure what to Google for.

If it was something like this

```
product = mock(Product.new)
```

I'd easily get it.

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, this is referred to as "monkey patching".

ruby has the concept of open classes, so at runtime you can mess around with it.

in the specific case of mocha, i assume that it is this piece of code here: https://github.com/freerange/mocha/blob/a7bc1b53ace895503b4b5d4915382aead4632e3e/lib/mocha/api.rb#L18-L22